# UART_Read_Text problem in XC8, pic isn't reciving string?

Tags: uart, xc8

I'm trying to send string via serial port to pic16.
Pic needs to split the string in several variables, and send it to motor driver.
But i have a problem:
it seems like string is not correctly readen..

I'm trying to turn some LEDs just for checking..

here is my code..

```
char data_rd[];


void main() 
  {
    TRISC = 0b10000000; //RC7 is digital input, the rest are outputs
    PORTC=0x00; 
    RC3=1;
    int speed_int=0;
    int shift_int=0;
    int direction_int=0;
    int on_off_int=0;

    UART_Init(9600);// Initialize UART module at baud rate 9600 bps


    while(1)
    {
      if(UART_Data_Ready())
    {
    UART_Read_Text(data_rd, 12); 
    __delay_ms(100);
  }     
 
char delim[] = "#";

char* speed = strtok(data_rd, delim);
char* shift = strtok(NULL, delim);
char* direction = strtok(NULL, delim);
char* on_off = strtok(NULL, delim);


speed_int=atoi(speed);
shift_int=atoi(shift);
direction_int=atoi(direction);
on_off_int=atoi(on_off);

RC0=on_off_int; // turn LED ON 
RC1=direction_int; // turn LED ON 
}
}
```

P.S. when I write string to variable then working correctly

```
char data_rd[]="123#456#1#1";
```